# how to make a binary file in c ---- struct within a struct

Tags: c, binaryfiles

how do i make a binary file if i have a linked list that looks like this:

```
typedef struct jor JOR;
typedef struct materials MATERIALS;

struct jor {
     int Number;
     char Date[20];
 MATERIALS *m;
 struct jor *next;
};

struct materials{
float Qty;
char Unit[20];
struct materials *next;
};
```

Comment: open the file with `b` mode: `handle = fopen(filename, "wb"); if (!handle) /* error */;`; then use `fwrite()` to write to it.

Comment: Please see the answers before voting on the question, it is **not** a trivial problem.

Comment: The answers don't make the question any less trivial. It is a trivial problem, you just need to design a binary encoding scheme

Answer (score 3):

If your struct was pointer free, you could just use a `fwrite` call and pass in a pointer to the structure.  However since your structure includes pointers you need to include special handling for reading and writing the data.

You will probably want to write a function that goes over each `jor`, writes out the `int` and `char[]` of `jor`, counts the number of materials, writes this number, then writes the data for each material (the `float` and `char[]`).  You could think about some other method where you don't write out the number of materials and `jor` entries, but it's probably a lot simpler just to write the numbers.

Untested, but you might do something like (I assume you linked list is terminated with a NULL pointer):

```
void WriteData(char[] szFilename, JOR* first)
{
    // Open binary file for writing (TODO: check successfully opened)
    FILE* fp = fopen(szFilename, "wb");

    // Count the number of `JOR`
    int i = 0; for (JOR* j = first; j != NULL; j = j->next;) i++;

    // Write the count to file
    fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    for (JOR* j = first; j != NULL; j = j->next)
    {
        // Write contents of `JOR`
        fwrite(j, sizeof(int) + sizeof(char)*20, 1, fp);

        // Count the number of `MATERIAL`
        int k = 0; for (MATERIAL* m = j->m; m != NULL; m = m->next) k++;

        // Write the materials to file
        fwrite(&k, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

        for (MATERIAL* m = j->m; m != NULL; m = m->next)
        {
            // Write contents of material
            fwrite(m, sizeof(float) + sizeof(char)*20, 1, fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Then for reading you would do something like:

```
JOR* ReadData(char[] szFilename)
{
    // Open data file (todo: check opened)
    FILE* fp = fopen(szFilename, "rb");

    // Read number of entries (todo: check read)
    int s; fread(&s, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    // Reserve memory for JOR entries (todo: check malloced)
    JOR* first = malloc(s*sizeof(JOR));

    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        // Read most of JOR
        fread(first+i, sizeof(int) + sizeof(char)*20, 1, fp);

        // Read number of materials in current JOR
        int d; fread(&s, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        MATERIAL* m = malloc(d*sizeof(MATERIAL));

        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
        {
            // Read most of MATERIAL
            fread(m+j, sizeof(float) + sizeof(char)*20, 1, fp);

            // Set next material
            m[j].next = m+j+1;
        }
        first[i].m = m;

        // Set next JOR
        first[i].next = first+i+1;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return first;
}
```